# Ошибка 400 при отправке запроса на html сервер

Tags: java, html, сервер

Всем привет, я пытаюсь подключиться к серверу html, отправляю туда запрос и каждый сервер мне возвращает ошибку HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request.

Вот код

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;



    public class start {


    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        String host = "google.com";
        Socket connection = new Socket (host,80);
        OutputStream sout;
        sout = connection.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
        String line = "GET / HTTP/1.1"
            +"\nHost: google.com"
            +"\nConnection: ke123ep-alive"
            +"\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
            +"\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
            +"\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
            +"\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch"
            +"\nAccept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4";
        out.writeUTF(line);
        System.out.println("запрос отправлен");
        InputStream in = connection . getInputStream ();
        System.out.println("ответ с сервера принят");
        int i=-1;
        while((i=in.read())!=-1){
            System.out.print((char)i);
        } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Очень похоже, что проблема во writeUTF: HTTP 1.1 передается не в UTF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String-) передает содержимое строки в [своем особенном формате](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8). Для отправки заголовков http достаточно передать строку в кодировке ASCII:

```
sout.write( line.getBytes( StandardCharsets.US_ASCII ) );
```

Учтите, что набор заголовков должен заканчиваться пустой строкой.

Comment: спасибо за быстрый ответ, но мне теперь не приходит ответ с сервера

Comment: `+"\n\n";` к вашей строке заголовков допишите.

Comment: всё работает, спасибо очень помогли)

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте лучше использовать для таких целей готовые инструменты для реализации Http клиента.

- В JavaSE7 есть HttpURLConnection. Примеры можно найти в интернете.
- Или Apache HttpComponents (Примеры: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)